# Visual Studio Asp.net core Angular template run tests automatically on build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I've created an Asp.net core + Angular project in Visual Studio, using the "Angular" template.
Would it be possible for each build in Visual Studio to run Angular (.spec) tests automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found by me, based on [@Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027847/182331)  answer:

In csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec  WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run test-onbuild" />
  </Target>
```

and in package.json i've added this

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-onbuild": "ng test --watch=false", <=====
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You can take a look on csproj file content it will have this setting

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

So I will add another step to this config like this

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run test" /> // add this
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

You see that I add another command to run test in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Angular8:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test", // run this command
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

So depend on what you need you can add step to publish phase

Comment: Thanks, this is working but the tests are launched only when publishing the project; instead i would to launch tests on each build..